# How to debug curl GET take up too much time?

Tags: php, laravel, curl, salesforce

I have recently linking my laravel app with salesforce API.
I have about 146 patients in my test salesforce account. I've noticed the curl is taking forever. I'm not sure is it because I did something wrong on my curl.

---

## I have tried

```
public static function patients(){

        try {
            $records = Salesforce::query('SELECT Id FROM Patients__c')->records;
            if(is_array($records)){
                $data = [];
                $session_id = Salesforce::getSessionID();

                foreach ($records as $i=>$record) {
                    $id = $record->Id;
                    $url = 'https://na3.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Patients__c/'.$id;

                    $ch = curl_init();
                    $timeout = 1;
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
                    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                        "Authorization: Bearer ".$session_id));
                    $result = curl_exec($ch);
                    curl_close($ch);
                    $result =  json_decode($result, true);
                    $data[$i] = $result;
                }

            }else{
                return $data;
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Log::error($e->getMessage());
            die($e->getMessage() . $e->getTraceAsString());
        }

        return $data;
    }
```

---

## Wireshark

I capture the loading time, it take about 25 seconds to load up the page, and it is just the simple data.

---

## cURL Info

This is the result of the first object of my foreach loop.

```
array:26 [▼
  "url" => "https://na3.salesforce.com/services/data/v36.0/sobjects/Patients__c/a005000000f0M3YAAU -H "Authorization: Bearer ******""
  "content_type" => null
  "http_code" => 400
  "header_size" => 47
  "request_size" => 256
  "filetime" => -1
  "ssl_verify_result" => 0
  "redirect_count" => 0
  "total_time" => 0.569035
  "namelookup_time" => 0.001719
  "connect_time" => 0.085617
  "pretransfer_time" => 0.26601
  "size_upload" => 0.0
  "size_download" => 10.0
  "speed_download" => 17.0
  "speed_upload" => 0.0
  "download_content_length" => -1.0
  "upload_content_length" => -1.0
  "starttransfer_time" => 0.568458
  "redirect_time" => 0.0
  "redirect_url" => ""
  "primary_ip" => "136.147.43.333"
  "certinfo" => []
  "primary_port" => 443
  "local_ip" => "10.20.100.333"
  "local_port" => 59777
]
```

---

What should I look into in order to improve this ?

I'm opening to any suggestions right now.

Comment: what have you timed? the curl request? the parsing of the data? the rendering of the page? or just the complete pageload time?

Comment: Its probably due to the curl operation being inside a foreach loop. Anyway to you make a single curl call with bulk ids?

Comment: @NDM : I will update my post with all those infos.

Comment: @AngadDubey : You said, "curl operation being inside a foreach loop", so how do u suggest it to do it the right way ? I'm open for any suggestions at this moment.

Comment: @ihue I would suggest checking the salesforce api docs to see if there is a route to get resources for multiple ids, i.e. pass an array of ids to the route instead of making a call for each id?

Comment: See the thing is, in order to GET all the info of each patient,  have a to make a call to each patient and construct them into an array. I did that all the time. What I am thinking it maybe I didn't close my cURL properly that could lead to the delay. Do you spot anything that I'm not suppose to do in my curl ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with curl but with the fact that you are making a *separate* HTTP request for each resource (patient) you want to retrieve. In the comments you state that there is no way to index, or list, all of the patients. I find this strange as it is a standard REST operation and Salesforce is extremely popular software. You should look further into the docs or maybe contact Salesforce to make sure this is the case.

If indeed you cannot index all patients and are required to make individual requests, then there isn't much you can do to speed up your consumption of the API so you will have to look into other methods. One thing you can do is to use [Scheduled Tasks](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/scheduling) to update your database in the background every `x` minutes/hours/days , essentially creating a local cache of your Salesforce patients. This way there will be no latency when your users access your application, and you can update the database in the background however frequently you need to.

Comment: I can index all patients base on prescriber ID. So first that's why I have list all prescribers to get the ID, and then loop through those IDs, and make each curl to `'https://na3.salesforce.com/services/data/v37.0/sobjects/Patients__c/'.$id` to get more details info about each patient. I'm not sure how elses, I would do that.

Comment: But definitely thanks for your answer, it definitely give me something to think about .

Comment: No problem. That being the case, you should definitely handle the API consumption behind the scenes as an automated task and save it to a database your application can access. Not only will it load faster for the user but it will save your server a ton of resources :)

Comment: I've also updated my post because I updated the way I did my cURL. Hopefully, you can spot something now. :)

Comment: I like the idea how loading them first and store into the database :) . If you don't mind, I ask. Which part or when of the application I should do that to reduce the latency ? See if I do that on the landing page, it will slow down my landing page. If I do it during the authentication, that will show down my auth process. So I guess - scripting ? or maybe cronjob ?

Comment: Look at the link in my answer :) . Scheduled Tasks in Laravel run behind the scenes. You set up one cron task and will run any tasks you make in your application however frequently you want.

Comment: I'll definitely learn more about that. Thank you so much pointing me to right track, and for a workaround !

Answer (score 1):

Just add the extra fields you want from patient to your original query, e.g. `SELECT Id,Name,foo__c FROM Patients__c` then you can ditch all the looping and curling all together.

Comment: soql docs https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql.htm

Comment: Sure, I'll try that. Thank you guys so much for your time and suggestion. :D

Comment: Your suggestions is awesome ! It works the latency is no longer happening. But how do I query the `entire` patient object within 1 query. What you suggested was just an ID. I want all the info about the patient.

Comment: Add the fields you care about to the query. If you don't want to hard code the field list, you can use the describeSObject API to get a list of fields and build it from that.